# Is the 100 Gang from the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, black-lightning

In the CW superhero show *Black Lightning*, the main gang that has power over the city the titular character lives in is called the 100 Gang. Is that an existing comic book organization? Is it at least based off of something from a run of Black Lightning comics? I know that its leader, Tobias Whale, is an existing character, but I don't know about the gang itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, although there are important differences

The 100 first appeared in *[Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane #105](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girlfriend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_105)* (1970) as a criminal group of 100 members that invaded Metropolis. They appeared several times in that series, and since Superman tended to stay on the sidelines in Lois' solo book, they were primarily opposed by [Rose Forrest](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Forrest_(Earth-One)), who developed the vigilante alter ego "Thorn" after her father was killed by the 100.

As best I can tell, they were last seen in [*Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane #130*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girlfriend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_130) (1973) before being revived in Black Lightning's first appearance in *[Black Lightning #1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_1)* (1977). This was also the first appearance of [Tobias Whale](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Tobias_Whale_(New_Earth)), introduced as the African American albino* leader of the 100 in Metropolis. At this point, Black Lightning became their primary enemy.

While the 100 did have normal street criminals and drug dealers, they also included more exotic criminals like [Merlyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlyn_(DC_Comics)) (Green Arrow's archnemesis), the cybernetic Steel-Fist Feeny, and the radioactivce Cyclotronic Man. Also after Tobias Whale was imprisoned, his successor increased the scope of the group and reformed them as [the 1000](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/One-Thousand), where they became a bigger threat to country.

<sub>* The TV show actor, [Krondon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krondon), is also an African American albino, so this is true to the comics.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I believe that they had their introduction in Lois Lane 105 (10-70) as the opponents of "The Thorn".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(comics)

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't also just link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_(DC_Comics)

Comment: My wife got home just as I was answering so I just went with what I had.  Besides, Wikipedia you can just go from one to the other.